# able to change the url but content (react-router)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Here's my setup :

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js

```
<Switch>
        {routes.map((route, idx) => {
             return route.component ? (
                 <Route
                    key={idx}
                    path={route.path}
                    exact={route.exact}
                    name={route.name}
                    render={props => (
                    <route.component {...props} />
                    )} />
                     ) : (null);
                     })}

</Switch>
```

routes.js

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        exact: true,
        component: Parameters,

    },
    {
        path: '/user-information',
        component: UserInformation
    },
]
```

Sidebar.js

```
 <Router>
                    <nav>
                        <Link to="/"><Icon type="heat-map" /></Link>
                        <Link to="/user-information"><Icon type="user" /></Link>
                    </nav>
 </Router>
```

the problem is when i click on sidebar link the url will chagne but the content won't change (but if i refresh the content will change as well)

I saw other questions as well and they all suggest using `import {withRouter} from 'react-router';` but in this example he is able to do it w/o it

Any idea would be appreciated it ?

Comment: Did you include Link from `react-router-dom`?

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of < BrowserRouter > in your app.  If so keep only the top level and remove the rest.. on side note use `route.path` as the `key` instead of `idx`

Comment: yeah, fixed i just found out that there are two `< BrowserRouter >` in my app